# Checking empty column values in case when and ignoring them

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I wrote the following query to check duplicates.

```
select s.*,m.IsMember_Ind,
        case    when REPLACE(s.[ Owner Mobile],' ','')
                    in (select cd.Mobile 
                        from Company_Detail cd
                        inner join MEMBERSHIP m
                        on cd.Company_ID = m.Company_ID
                        where m.IsMember_Ind = 1)
                    then 'Match'            
                else ' ' end as OwnerMobileMatch,
        case when REPLACE(s.[ Contact Number],' ','')
                    in (select cd.Mobile 
                        from Company_Detail cd
                        inner join MEMBERSHIP m
                        on cd.Company_ID = m.Company_ID
                        where m.IsMember_Ind = 1)
                    then 'Match' else ' ' end as ContactMobileMatch             
from COMPANY c
inner join surreynonmembers s
on c.TTR_ID = s.[Company ID]
left outer join MEMBERSHIP m
on m.Company_ID = c.Company_ID
```

My problem is, the case statement returns as a match when finds an empty value which I do not need. How can I modify this query to return if there is only a value?

Comment: Why not just use another case or if with ISNULL() funtion?

Comment: Or include `AND s.[ Owner Mobile] <> ''` in OwnerMobileMatch and `AND s.[ Contact Number] <> ''` in ContactMobileMatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
GO
SELECT s.*
    ,m.IsMember_Ind
    ,CASE 
        WHEN REPLACE(s.[ Owner Mobile], ' ', '') IN (
                SELECT cd.Mobile
                FROM Company_Detail cd
                INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIP m ON cd.Company_ID = m.Company_ID
                WHERE m.IsMember_Ind = 1
                AND ISNULL(s.[ Owner Mobile], '') <> ''
                )
            THEN 'Match'
        ELSE ' '
        END AS OwnerMobileMatch
    ,CASE 
        WHEN REPLACE(s.[ Contact Number], ' ', '') IN (
                SELECT cd.Mobile
                FROM Company_Detail cd
                INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIP m ON cd.Company_ID = m.Company_ID
                WHERE m.IsMember_Ind = 1
                AND ISNULL(s.[ Contact Number], '')<> ''
                )
            THEN 'Match'
        ELSE ' '
        END AS ContactMobileMatch
FROM COMPANY c
INNER JOIN surreynonmembers s ON c.TTR_ID = s.[Company ID]
LEFT JOIN MEMBERSHIP m ON m.Company_ID = c.Company_ID

GO
```